# Points from python directly to ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcpy

I have a python code that is generating coordinates one by one. Is there a way to display them directly in ArcMap as they are generated? I am aware of the insert cursor but the lock on the table prevents python from writing into it.

**Ok, now that I used the Python window in ArcMap new error has occured. Could it be because the "czk" is a list?**

Here is the code:

```
czk=[413960.0, 47130.0]
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor("C:/GIS/AlJeba/Tocke/Tocke.shp", ("SHAPE@XY"))
for row in czk:
    cursor.insertRow(row)
del cursor
```

And here is the error:

Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 333, in 
TypeError: argument must be sequence of values

Comment: Is this a stand-alone python script, or with arcpy run within Arcmap?

Comment: If by run in ArcMap you mean using Python window in program then no. I'm running the script in the Python Shell using IDLE.

Comment: Why is the insert cursor not working.  Is this layer being edited by another user?  Can you post your code?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to revise it with any requested clarifications, please?

Comment: Can you include the czk list in your code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing in Shape@XY as the argument for the field names. This expects a tuple of the feature's centroid x,y coordinates to be passed in when you use the insert cursor ( see http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w0000000t000000)

However, czk=[413960.0, 47130.0] is a list containing two floating point numbers.
When you say:

```
    for row in czk:
        cursor.insertRow(row)
```

You are only passing a single floating point number in when it expects a tuple with two items in it (one x and one y coordinate).

If 413960.0, 47130.0 is your x,y pair then you need to change your code to something like this:

```
    czk=(413960.0, 47130.0)
    cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor("C:/GIS/AlJeba/Tocke/Tocke.shp", ("SHAPE@XY"))
    cursor.insertRow(czk)
    del cursor
```

Comment: A yes now I completely understand. The cursor was trying to insert x into first row and y in the second.

Thank you for explanation

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
czk = [(413960.0, 47130.0)]
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor("C:/GIS/AlJeba/Tocke/Tocke.shp", ("SHAPE@XY"))
for row in czk:
    cursor.insertRow(row)

del cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to attempt the code in the second example on [this](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w0000000t000000) help page?
Is your czk list in the same structure as the example, also note that you are using () instead of [] around you field list when you create the cursor.

I think this is just a case of you stopping and reading the help file to make sure you are writing your code carefully?

Comment: I don't know. I read the entire page but in the end I had to convert czk to tuple and append it to new empty list. Well now it works, thank you. However I thought that ArcMap will be adding points to the map as they are created and inserted to the table one by one. Is this even possible?

Comment: Also had to delete parentheses around "SHAPE@XY".

Comment: I don't think that happens nor would you want it. The whole map display would keep refreshing which is a time consuming process. So insert the points then refresh the map display.

Comment: So you think this is not a good idea? I thought it would be nice for a presentation to see how script actually works.